# How to read file in webRoot dir from EJB3?

Tags: file-io, glassfish, ejb

I have an EmailSrvc Stateless Session Bean (EJB3), deployed on Glassfish. The bean needs to read an email template stored in /emailTemplates/someTemplate.html, process the template and send the email. The questions:

1) is this web dir suggested above an appropriate location for keeping the email templates?

2) how do I reference the file? I'd like to avoid direct filesystem paths as the server may be clustered. I was thinking I could get the webRootfolder via the ServletContext, but I haven't figured out how to look it up from within the bean.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just figured I can put the emailTemplates folder underneath `WEB-INF/classes` and get an inputStream of the file I need like this :

```java
InputStream in = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("emailTemplates/someTemplate.html");
```

Not sure I like having the templates in the classes folder however, it doesn't seem appropriate. Hopefully somebody else can propose a better solution?